# $.getJSON won't return JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm developing off files hosted by a small webserver on my desktop. I'm trying to call the `$.getJSON` method to import a JSON file, but I keep getting the following error:

> Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

According to some research, this is because the file I'm calling is being  returned as HTML. I can't find any details as to *why* that is.

The variable `recipesLoc` is set to `http://localhost:1337/recipes.json`.  I have verified the integrity of the JSON file via JSONLint, so I know that isn't the issue.  Can someone please lend me some direction?

Here's my JS, mostly from an example:

```
function loadJSON(){
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
$.getJSON(recipesLoc, function(data){
    console.log(data)
    console.log("getJson");
})
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + data);
})
.fail(function( data, textStatus, error ) {
    console.log(recipesLoc)
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.warn(data.responseText)
    console.warn(data);
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
}
```

Adding the line:

```
recipes = $.get(recipesLoc, function(data){
    console.log("Data is: "+data);
})
```

logs:

```
Data is: 

    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bdu.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hi</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Why is it returning the HTML in which the JavaScript file is included?

Comment: Can you share the response of calling URL(`recipesLoc`)

Comment: How do I get the pure response? Navigating to the URL gives me an HTML page with the JSON; but, that's through a browser, so expected.

Comment: Use `$.get(..)` instead, that function returns the response as string.

Comment: '[object Object]'
From: <code>alert("'"+$.get(recipesLoc)+"'")</code>

Comment: What is that?  `console.log(data)`??

Comment: That was me trying to print everything I could to figure out why I was getting HTML back.

Comment: Okay, progress.  I did this:

recipes = $.get(recipesLoc, function(data){
        console.log("Data is: "+data);
    })

Which resulted in this:

Data is: <html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bdu.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hi</p>
    </body>
</html>

The question is now: Why would directing $.get(recipesLoc) to my JSON file return the HTML that is calling the javascript?

Edit: Comments really don't like formatting..

Comment: As you can see from your posted data, you are either a.) not requesting the right JSON backend or b.) your routing script - if any - does not know that it should return JSON rather than a web page. It'd recommend using your "Developer Tools" in your browser (each browser has these nowadays) and examine the "Network tab" to see the requests your script performs.

Comment: You need to debug the server side of this.

Comment: Are you sure that you are requesting the right JSON file and not being redirected to a 404 page which displays the HTML code?

Comment: as @MikeMcCaughan has mentioned, make a little debug on your server side.

Comment: Ah!  Okay, I was operating on the assumption that $.get() and $.getJSON() were directed at a file, not as something for the server to interpret.  I see that assumption was now wrong, and will build out a webserver instead of using nbd's http-server.  Thanks! :)